# How we can print array variable in log file of Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, log

I am trying to print array variable contents into a log file.

In Magento 1, it was possible using `Mage::log(print_r($arr, 1), null, 'logfile.log');`

For Magento 2, in class file I have written following code:

```
protected $_logger;

    public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger) {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }


private function getValuesAsHtmlList(\Magento\Framework\Object $object) {
        $options = $this->getOptions($object);
       //$this->_logger->addDebug($options );
        $this->_logger->log(100,null,$options);
    }
```

When I execute the code after clearing the cache, `Debug.log` & `system.log` files are not showing the array contents.

Please share if anyone has any idea about it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Suppose your array is

`$a = array ('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana', 'c' => array ('x', 'y', 'z'));`

then you have to write below code to write proper array format in your log file

```
$this->_logger->log(100,print_r($a,true));
```

It will print in you log file

```
[2015-11-09 06:58:27] main.DEBUG: Array
(
    [a] => apple
    [b] => banana
    [c] => Array
        (
            [0] => x
            [1] => y
            [2] => z
        )

)
 {"is_exception":false} []
```

Comment: With this approach, I needed to look at the `var/log/debug.log` file for the output

Answer (score 11):

See declaration of log method

```
public function  \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::log($level, $message, array $context = array());
```

So, you need code like

```
$this->_logger->log(100, json_encode($options));
```

Comment: I'd print_r($options, true) myself instead of json encoding. But preferences \o/

Comment: better yet: `$this->_logger->debug(json_encode($options));`

Answer (score 6):

This method works well for me.

```
$this->logger->info(print_r($myArray, true));
```

Then check your `system.log` file.

Answer (score 1):

For array and also object just use

```
public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger) {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }

public function logs(){

$this->logger->info(print_r($orderData, true));
}
```

and check the output in `/var/log/debug.log` file

Answer (score 0):

```
protected $_logger;

    public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger) {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }

public function logs(){
  $level='log';
$this->_logger->log($level,'errorlog1234', array( array('test1'=>'123', 'test2' => '456'), array('a'=>'b') ));

}
```

Try This it will print array.
**Tested !**

Answer (score 0):

I see core file uses var_export:

```
//File: vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/AbstractIpn.php
/**
 * Log debug data to file
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function _debug()
{
    if ($this->_config && $this->_config->getValue('debug')) {
        $this->logger->debug(var_export($this->_debugData, true));
    }
}
```